# Отправка фото в диалог ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api

Вот я получаю ссылку для загрузки фото

```
curl -G https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer?access_token=$token
```

Получаю, саму ссылку и отправляю файл фотографии на сервер

```
curl -G -v -F "photo=@/sdcard/.secret/09_08_2017_17_02_59.jpg" $upload_url
```

Начинает бегать информация о загрузке и в конце я вижу JSON с массивом `photo`. В документации `messages.send` указано что нужно передавать параметром `attachment`

```
photo<owner_id>_<media_id>
```

`owner_id` это мой id, получается? А `media_id` это то что мне возвращает ВК после загрузки фото в параметре `server`?

```
curl -G "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=279000722&attachment=$ath&message=test&access_token=$token"
```

Вообщем, что-то здесь неправильно и я не пойму, что... Мне приходит сообщение с текстом `test` но без фото :(

Comment: Вы забываете вызывать `photos.saveMessagesPhoto`, читайте документацию внимательнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде чем торопиться отправить сообщение следует сохранить фотографию у пользователя с помощью метода [photos.saveMessagesPhoto](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveMessagesPhoto). Вам нужно передать этому методу информацию, полученную после загрузки файла; поля photo, server и hash. Обратите внимание, поле photo надо раскодировать перед отправкой (в простейшем случае убрать все обратные слэши, но в общем случае без специализированного парсера, к сожалению, не обойтись).

А после этого в ответе вы получите интересуемые вас идентификаторы.

Не забудьте ознакомиться с [руководством по загрузке фотографий в ЛС](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=4.+%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Спасибо, продолжил мучиться с парсингом в shell